# When does the IVP $\dot{y}=y^2,~y(0)=1$ have a unique solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

When does the IVP

$$\begin{cases}\dot{y}=y^2 \\ y(0)=1,\end{cases}$$

with $(x,y)\in \Bbb R\times\Bbb R$ have a unique solution?

For

$$\begin{cases}\dot{y}=f(x,y) \\ y(0)=y_0 \end{cases}$$

when do we have a unique solution, no solution, or infinitely many solutions?
i want to ask the first IVP have a unique solution in which of the following intervals..
a)($-\infty$,$\infty$)
b)($-\infty$,1)
c)(-2,2)
d)(-1,$\infty$).and how the answer is given option b . please tell me how it comes

Comment: The $\belongs$ command does not seem to be rendering the way you want it to. Do you want the symbol, $\in$? Also by $(R,R)$, do you mean $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: yes. i meant this

Comment: Tri `\in` ${}{}{}$

Comment: What do you mean by solution? Do you mean a function $x \mapsto y(x)$ defined for $x \in (-\epsilon, \epsilon)$ for some small $\epsilon$? This is usually called a 'local solution'. Or do you mean a solution $y : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, that is, defined for all 'time'? You should look up Picard iteration, which is a typical method for establishing _local_ uniqueness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can solve $\dot y=y^2$ where $y\ne0$ noting that $\dot y/y^2$ is the derivative of $-1/y$. Integrating this yields that the unique local solution on a neighborhood of $0$ is such that $1/y(x)=-x+1/y(0)$. By inspection, if $y(0)=1$, the maximal solution is $y(x)=1/(1-x)$ for $x$ in $(-\infty,1)$.

Comment: what do you mean by maximal solution.and thanks

Comment: The solution defined on the maximal interval around x=0 on which a solution exists.

Answer (score 0):

The IVP has a uniaue solution by [Picard-Lindelof Theorem](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem).

Comment: please someone help

Comment: @Mhenni how do you apply the theorem here $f(x,y)=y^2$ is not lipschitz!